# I need a chip tantalum capacitor c it has 107c 01JB1 on it

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator

It goes in a 8A linear voltage regulator.   It is a  Chip tantalum capacitor c  marks on it is  107C 01JB1 I do not know the value or rating of it or where to get one any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

107C should be 100uF and 16V.
The numbers are how many picofarads, the third digit is the multiplier, so it's  $$10 * 10^7$$
Which is 100 million picofarads or 100 microfarads.

The easy way to remember is that 105 is 1uF, then for each number less you add a decimal place, for example 104 is 0.1uF, each number more you multiply by 10, so 108 would be 1000uF.

The C is the voltage rating.
F = 2.5V
G = 4V
A = 10V
C = 16V
D = 20V
E = 25V
V = 35V
T = 50V

The rest is probably a date code, which is generally manufacturer specific.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!!!!